# Class 'Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider' not found using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am getting an error message with pdf export package "Class "Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade" not found".... Have added Barryvdh\DomPDFServiceProvider::class and 'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF::class to config/app.php.
[image]
**controller**

```
 public function index(){

        $data = Employee::all();
        // share data to view
        view()->share('employee',$data);
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf_view', $data);
        // download PDF file with download method
        return $pdf->download('pdf_file.pdf');
 }
```

Comment: Did you install any package providing that class?

Comment: first make sure you install the package by running this command ```composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf```, also following the guidelines in this link ```https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf```

Answer (score 0):

1. First, check whether the package is installed or not in the vendor folder by using the following path.
   vendor/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/src/ServiceProvider.php.

   If the package is not found, run the "composer install" command in the root project.
2. And let you check the following code in the config/app.php file

```
'providers' => [
     Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class,
],
'aliases' => [
    'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class,
],
```

If the above code is not found in the app.php, add this line.